# Creating string array with recursion

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, recursion

I should take strings from user WORDSIZE times.
And I should do this with recursion.
In this code any loop, any static variables, and string library function not allowed.
So I send count and n variable as a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WORDSIZE 5
/* I accepted wordsize as number of the words to be delete. To delete "hello"and"world", wordsize should be 2 */

int take_words(char (*array)[WORDSIZE], int *m, int *cnt)
{
    if((*m) == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        scanf("%s", array[*cnt]);
        getchar();
        printf("(1)This word will be entered %s\n", array[*cnt]);   
        //This printf works correctly.
        (*m)--;
        (*cnt)++;
        take_words(array, m, cnt);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char (*words)[WORDSIZE]; 
    int n=WORDSIZE, count=0;
    printf("Enter the words one by one\n");
    take_words(words, &n, &count);
    for(int i=0; i<WORDSIZE; i++)
        printf("(2)Occured array's %ith term: %s\n",i, words[i]);
}
```

Problem is that, althoug printf(1) works correct, printf(2) in main doesn't give the correct result. Here is the output:

```
Enter the words one by one
hello
(1)This word will be entered hello
darkness
(1)This word will be entered darkness
my
(1)This word will be entered my
old
(1)This word will be entered old
friend
(1)This word will be entered friend
(2)Occured array's 0th term: hellodarknmy
(2)Occured array's 1st term: darknmy
(2)Occured array's 2nd term: my
(2)Occured array's 3rd term: old
(2)Occured array's 4th term: friend
```

Array couldn't create right. How could I hanlde this?

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized non-static local variable `words`, which is indetrminate.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<WORDSIZE; i++)` this is a loop while any loop is not allowed.

Comment: @nicholai_hel It is totally unclear why the number of entered words is specified as WORDSIZE. The assignment as described does not make a sense.

Comment: @MikeCAT This loop is just to contol whether array is occured right or not, I have to delete it after be sure array is correct. So how I can prevent this undefined behavior?

Comment: @EOF Hmm, I think I can add a terminating condition to if(m==0) statement, like adding \0 or etc. But array[*cnt]  is a string and I couldn't make a simple assignment to a string without string functions, righy?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Unfortunately it is not my chocie to define wordsize. All the above are necessary for the rest of the code.